# Python column hierarchy creation for groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a question I can't get my head around, although I'm sure it's dead simple.
I import an excel file, with sales figures of cars.
**I need to be able to report on it by country.**
The country is not part of the file, but I have the info of all the cars of each country. (I can create another DataFrame from it, or a list, or dict...)
My idea was to create a hierarchie in the columns. I just can't figure out how.

```
    import pandas as pd
    german=['BMW','Audi','Mercedes','Volkswagen']
    italian=['Fiat','Ferrari']
    
    toclean=pd.DataFrame([['car','4','5',10,20,15,50,20,13,24]],
            columns=['type','wheels','seats','BMW','Audi','Mercedes','Volkswagen','Fiat','Ferrari','SEAT'])
```

| type | wheels | seats | BMW | Audi | Mercedes | Volkswagen | Fiat | Ferrari | SEAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car. | 4 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 15 | 50 | 20 | 13 | 24 |

Comment: Are `['type', 'wheels' 'seats']` are a unique key to this DataFrame, and what should happen with the `'SEAT'` column? Is it possible for this `df` to have more rows for different types,and wheels?

Comment: @ALollz : thank you for this reply : 
Just for the records : in the real challenge this goes about SKU and supermarket sales, while some supermarkets are part of a chain and others are independent. And I need to report on the shop and chain/independent level.
But the information of a shop being part of a chain is not in the excel file.
I thought I simplified the problem by using cars but I might have missed my goal ;-)

> Actually yes.... type-wheels-seats are unique keys. 
> The SEAT should indeed be a result on it's own, next to Italy and Germany....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def country(brand):
    if brand in german:
        return 'germany'
    elif brand in italian:
        return 'italy'
    else:
        return None

long_df = toclean.melt()
long_df['country'] = long_df['variable'].map(country)
long_df
     variable value  country
0        type   car     None
1      wheels     4     None
2       seats     5     None
3         BMW    10  germany
4        Audi    20  germany
5    Mercedes    15  germany
6  Volkswagen    50  germany
7        Fiat    20    italy
8     Ferrari    13    italy
9        SEAT    24     None

long_df.groupby('country')['value'].sum()
country
germany    95
italy      33
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Only : in my real dataset I have +30 countries & 100 of brands. ;-) but you pointed me in the good direction, I'll try it and let you know ! Thanks for the help! Appreciated.

Comment: This works great, thank you for the solution!